# How to auto refresh data in android studio every second?

Tags: java, android, okhttp

I am new to android studio, I am making an app that gets the json of a field in thingspeak, but I don't know how can I make an auto refresh to the data I get every second. Can you please help me?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private TextView mTextViewResult;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mTextViewResult = findViewById(R.id.text_view_result);


        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

        // Read field url from thingspeak
        String url = "https://api.thingspeak.com/channels/XXXXXXX/fields/1.json?api_key=XXXXXXXXXXXXX&results=2";

        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(url)
                .build();

        client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(@NonNull okhttp3.Call call, @NonNull Response response) throws IOException {
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                       
                       // this is what I want to refresh every second

                        final String myResponse = response.body().string();

                        MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                mTextViewResult.setText(myResponse);
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }


          



        });
    }
}
```

Comment: I think it's better to open a socket connection. sending reqest every one second is not logical

Comment: Note: this logic is in your Android app. It doesn't happen in Android Studio itself like your title implies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution finally, I placed the data request inside the following code and it worked perfectly:

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();
Runnable refresh = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // data request
            handler.postDelayed(this, 5000);
        }
    };
handler.postDelayed(refresh, 5000);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a CountDown Timer . Set the timer for 1 second and  in onFinish method call request data .

```
       new CountDownTimer(1000, 1000) {
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
               
            }
            public void onFinish() {
               //Request Data
            }
        }.start();
```

Comment: I tried to use it but it is not working for me idk why.